# How to get a DateTimeOffset having local time information

Tags: c#, nodatime

I have these input strings:

```
var timeStr = "03:22";
var dateStr = "2018/01/12";
var format = "yyyy/MM/dd";
var timeZone = "Asia/Tehran";
```

This is the information of a time that I have, the the `timeStr` is in `Asia/Tehran` time zone and is not in UTC.

Using NodaTime, how can I get a DateTimeOffset object having this information containing correct offset in it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's convert all your information into appropriate Noda Time types:

```
// Input values (as per the question)
var timeStr = "03:22";
var dateStr = "2018/01/12";
var format = "yyyy/MM/dd";
var timeZone = "Asia/Tehran";

// The patterns we'll use to parse input values
LocalTimePattern timePattern = LocalTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("HH:mm");
LocalDatePattern datePattern = LocalDatePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture(format);

// The local parts, parsed with the patterns and then combined.
// Note that this will throw an exception if the values can't be parsed -
// use the ParseResult<T> return from Parse to check for success before
// using Value if you want to avoid throwing.
LocalTime localTime = timePattern.Parse(timeStr).Value;
LocalDate localDate = datePattern.Parse(dateStr).Value;
LocalDateTime localDateTime = localDate + localTime;

// Now get the time zone by ID
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZone];

// Work out the zoned date/time being represented by the local date/time. See below for the "leniently" part.
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.InZoneLeniently(zone);
// The Noda Time type you want would be OffsetDateTime
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = zonedDateTime.ToOffsetDateTime();
// If you really want the BCL type...
DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset = zonedDateTime.ToDateTimeOffset();
```

Note the "InZoneLeniently" which handles ambiguous or skipped local date/time values like this:

> ambiguous values map to the earlier of the alternatives, and "skipped" values are shifted forward by the duration of the "gap".

That may or may be what you want. There's also `InZoneStrictly` which will throw an exception if there isn't a single instant in time represented by the given local date/time, or you can call `InZone` and pass in your own `ZoneLocalMappingResolver`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the nodatime DateTimeOffset object you can do as such:

```
        var timeStr = "03:22";
        var dateStr = "2018/01/12";
        // DateTime.Parse can deal with this format without specs            
        // var format = "yyyy/MM/dd";
        var timeZone = "Asia/Tehran";


        var date = DateTime.Parse(timeStr + " " + dateStr);
        var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZone];
        var timespanOffset = zone.GetUtcOffset(SystemClock.Instance.Now).ToTimeSpan();
        var result = new DateTimeOffset(date, timespanOffset);

        Console.Write(result.ToUniversalTime());
```

The result is: `1/11/2018 10:52:00 PM +00:00` which corresponds to Tehran time being GMT +4,5

Comment: Thank you. Format can change in future. That's the reason I used a variable for it.

Comment: Why are passing now to `GetUtcOffset`? Shouldn't it be the `date` so it considers the offset for that date?

Comment: It's an implementation detail of the library, seems like datetimezoneprovider can't figure out it's offset without the knowledge od current utc time.

Comment: I don't think it requires current time. It requires the date we are looking for its offset. For a given timezone, there are different offset at different days in the year because of DSTs.

Comment: In my example `var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Asia/Tehran"]` contains the timezone information. if you print out  as it is instantiated now with `SystemClock.Instance.Now` `timespanOffset.ToString()` returns `04:30:00`. That's the correct offset from utc.

Comment: `zone.GetUtcOffset(Instant instant)` requires an instant as a parameter. If you think about this means that you could get offsets from different timezones if you would pass in a different timezone instant, gmt+1 for example. I guess that's the main reason for this implementation.

Comment: This is a flawed approach IMO. It could give the wrong result, assuming I've understood the OP's requirement correctly, which is to get the offset *for the local date/time specified*, not the offset of the time right now. See my answer for how to do this all in Noda Time, specifying how you want ambiguous/skipped local values to be handled.

Comment: Flawed approach due to `SystemClock.Instance.Now` being system/culture dependent? Was I simply lucky to get a correct offset of 4:30, due to my machine having a correct UTC time?

@JonSkeet I was also curious why is it that `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZone]` doesn't provide a default utc offset property?

Comment: @pijemcolu: Flawed approach due to the offset "now" quite possibly being different to the offset at the date/time specified by `timeStr` and `dateStr`. There's no such concept as the "default" UTC offset for a time zone - even if you ignore daylight saving time, the UTC "standard" offset can vary over the course of history.